# How to jump to the manage permission page in Settings App with code?

Tags: android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow

The path is:

Settings -> Apps ->(In Apps list) XXX App -> Permissions.

Below is the log when I enter into the "manage permission" page manually.

> 08-11 02:36:02.327: I/ActivityManager(775): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MANAGE_APP_PERMISSIONS cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.permission.ui.ManagePermissionsActivity (has extras)} from uid 1000 on display 0

And furthermore, I searched the two key words `MANAGE_APP_PERMISSIONS` and `ManagePermissionsActivity` in the source code of the Android "M" preview1, both were not found.
Can someone can help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to call `startActivity()` with that intent because it requires `android.permission.GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS` and this permission it's not avaiable for third-party apps. What you can do is to use the `APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` intent.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Is there a root method to go to the permissions screen ?

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible. I tried following methods but both require `android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS`.

```
// Use Action
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.MANAGE_APP_PERMISSIONS");
intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", packageName);
startActivity(intent);

// Use Component
Intent intent = new Intent();
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.packageinstaller", "com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.ManagePermissionsActivity");
intent.setComponent(comp);
intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", packageName);
startActivity(intent);
```